# If I didn't get an answer about statistics on math.stackexachange should I post duplicate on stats.stack?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, math-stackexchange

I asked a question on math.stackexchange.com and I didn't receive any answer.

Can I post it on stats.stackexchange? The question is from category statistics, numerics and algorithms.

Comment: This is not how the sites work. Either it fitted there, or here. So if it didn't fit there, you can flag it as a candidate for migration to our site. You should not post duplicates. Alternatively, you may delete and re-post the question on our site if it fitts here.

Comment: What @Tim says is documented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Cross-posting is discouraged. Positively, do delete there and post here.

Comment: Don't delete and repost unless you can't flag for migration as Tim suggested.